# Tomcat 8 does not release Port 80 at restart on Windows

Tags: windows, http, tomcat, server, port

i have got some strange issues with Tomcat 8 and Port 80. We switched the standard connector to Port 80. I checked the port bindings on netstat. Port 80 is not bound. I start Tomcat8 everything works fine. After that I restart the tomcat application and it prompts that Port 80 can't be bound. Again a view in netstat -ao, Port 80 is not bound. Does anybody had this issue before?

OS is Windows Server 2012.

Best Michael!

Comment: Are you running Tomcat as a Windows service?

Comment: Sounds like both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791717/tomcat-8-will-not-startup-on-free-port and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773720/windows-keeping-port-locked-after-shutting-down-tomcat

Comment: Looks like Microsoft broke this for you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666952/address-bind-exception-in-tomcat