# How to release the port used by a terminated process

Tags: windows, networking, port

I have a service that was running on port `8080`. I restarted the said service and when it started again, it was already giving an error that the port was being used.

[image]

I then tried **Process Hacker 2**, **TCPView** and **CurrPorts** to find the process using the port and terminate it but unfortunately, I cannot find it.

I then have to restart the whole hardware/machine just to free up the port which is not preferable. And if I restart the service again, I have to restart the whole system... again.

I'm using **Windows Server 2012 R2**. The service was started by [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).

So how do I release this port that is being used but is not really being used?

> Note: This issue only started a few days ago, before that everything was OK. (right after a windows update)

Comment: Windows Update problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666952/address-bind-exception-in-tomcat

Comment: @focusardi that would make sense, I did notice a **Windows Update** right before the issue started.