# windows keeping port locked after shutting down tomcat

Tags: windows, tomcat, port, locked

I have a problem that is happening on 3 different sets of server at different sites.

The issue is that after I shut down a Tomcat (7 and 8.5 versions) service on Windows server and then try to restart the service it will not start because tomcat thinks the ports are still in use.

Here is a snippet of the error and it throws the error for 8080, 8443, and 8009 when trying to restart this specific server:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411)
at 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
```

I have tried finding any services using the ports with TCPView and task manager, using the netstat -ano finds nothing that matches the ports, and I have not been able to find anything anywhere on the system that indicates the ports are in use.

This started a couple months ago and I have been having it start happening on three different site's servers.  All are running windows server 2012 or newer.

So wondering if anyone else has run into this or knows what to try to get the ports to free up as the only option I have found is to restart the system to clear the ports.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791717/tomcat-8-will-not-startup-on-free-port

Comment: Looks like Microsoft broke you guys. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666952/address-bind-exception-in-tomcat

Comment: I have the same kind of issue after Windows updates...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429224/address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-but-no-process-is-listed-using-port-with-netsta/51669524#51669524